# Iphone compatibility

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, ipod-touch

I'm working with a developer to build an iphone app and am running into a compatibility issue. The app is buggy when running on a Ipod touch running IOS 3.1.3. However, a later version of IOS on another Ipod touch runs fine (not sure of the os but was recently refreshed). He's compiling in standard mode (from what i can tell, that supports ARM6 and ARM7).

1. I was told the latest SDK doesn't allow for 3.1.3 emulation so he can't troubleshoot the incompatibility. Is this true?
2. If so, how do you write backwards compatible iphone apps?
3. Will the app store accept apps not compiled using the latest SDK?
4. Is it common to write iphone apps that are backwards compatible even to the first generation of iphone?
5. If he sets the target os to 3.1.3, if there is an incompatible method call, shouldn't the compiler throw an error?

Thanks!

Comment: The answer to (5) is, sadly, no. That would be nice, but it's not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was told the latest SDK doesn't
>   allow for 3.1.3 emulation so he can't
>   troubleshoot the incompatibility. Is
>   this true?

Yes, it's true. The simulator included with the iOS 4.3 SDK supports iOS 3.2 and later.

> If so, how do you write backwards
>   compatible iphone apps?

If you need to support 3.1.3 or older, you should test on a device running that version of the OS.

> Will the app store accept apps not
>   compiled using the latest SDK?

I don't think so. However, you can use the current SDK to build for 3.1.3 -- just set the deployment target to 3.1.3. The limitation is that you just can't test or debug on the simulator (which isn't all that useful for actual testing anyway).

> Is it common to write iphone apps that
>   are backwards compatible even to the
>   first generation of iphone?

No. Third party apps weren't a possibility for the first iPhone OS (which wasn't even called iOS at that point). It's probably possible to write an app that works back to 2.0, but the oldest version that sane developers would consider would be 3.1.2 or 3.1.3.

> If he sets the target os to 3.1.3, if
>   there is an incompatible method call,
>   shouldn't the compiler throw an error?

That'd be very nice, and something that many developers have asked for, but that doesn't happen right now.